# Laravel Problems with routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have `user` and I've created a profile button such as each user can look for their data.

In `UserController.php` I have this function:

```
/*
* @Get("user/profile/{id}")
*/
public function profile($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

I call it from a view like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
    <?= link_to('user/profile/'.Auth::user()->id, $title = 'Perfil'); ?>
    </li>
    @if(Auth::user()->type_id == 1)
    <li><a href="{!!URL::to('/user')!!}">Administrar</a></li>
    @endif
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="{!!URL::to('/logout')!!}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

That button takes me to the URL I want such as `/user/profile/6` for example, but it sends me this error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Can you add your `routes.php` file here? Hard to debug this otherwise. Also what are the contents of line 161?

Comment: Do you have "laravelcollective/annotations" installed in your composer file?  If so, what's in your $scanRoutes array in the AnnotationsServiceProvider? Also, which version of Laravel are you using (major.minor.build)?

Comment: Yes i've installed annotations, using laravel 5.1, dont't know what you meen with $scanRoutesarray

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say where the route is currently going, but I would change the line:

```
<li>
<?= link_to('user/profile/'.Auth::user()->id, $title = 'Perfil'); ?>
</li>
```

To the `blade` version:

```
<li><a href="{!! url("/user/profile/".Auth::user()->id) !!}">Profile</a></li>
```

Also, make sure you have a `route` that matches it in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get("/user/profile/{id}", "UsersController@profile");
```

I'm honestly not sure why you're mixing `<?= link_to(); ?>` and `{!! url() !!}` blade syntax on the same page... Either way, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

THanks, just got to repair it the problem was in the User controller that didn't got the annotation, it should be this way:

```
/**
* @Get("user/profile/{id}")
*/
public function profile($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

It seems to be the same, it's only the second * in the coment, as silly as that.